# how to point to back of generic list c#

Tags: c#, list, generics

Is there a way to point to the last item added to a generic list in c# ? Like the back() for a vector in c++

Comment: please reword your question, it doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();

for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
   myList.Add (i);
}

Console.WriteLine (String.Format ("Last item: {0}", myList[myList.Count - 1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the 3.5 framework

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    public static class Program {
       public static void Main() {
           Console.WriteLine(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }.Last()); // outputs - 3
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`list.Last()` ?

Comment: Seems that I have to 'think LINQ' more ... :)

Comment: Last() probably wraps around list[list.Count-1] so it doesn't even bother after all :-)